# Wait for subtree widgets to finish loading async data before showing them

Tags: dart, flutter

I have multiple widget components in my app, and each component requires different data from the server. On initState of the component, I fetch the data it requires.

When the app opens I fetch what components to show from the server. Example: show only component 1 and 3. How can I wait for 1 and 3 to load without showing them initially ( just showing a loader) and when both are done loading, I would show them or show an error page?

Comment: use `FutureBuilder` (or `StreamBuilder` or `AnimatedBuilder`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary to validate if the data is ready, if not you can just show a `CircleProgressIndicator`, something like this :

```
        class _LoadingComponentsState extends State<LoadingComponents> {
          bool waiting = true;

          loadingAsyncTask() async {
            //.. your logic

            setState(() {
              waiting = false;
            });
          }

          @override
          void initState() {
            loadingAsyncTask();
            super.initState();
          }

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              child: waiting
                  ? Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                  : ListView(
                      children: [
                        //your data...
                      ],
                    ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: My problem is that the children widgets fetch their own data, I want to wait for all the children widgets to fetch their data before i remove the circular progress indicator